# Event on many to many models in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models `Contact` and `Event`that have a many2many relationship. I need to store(save/cache) the count of each relationship when the relationship change. For example:

- Person A has Event 1, Event2
- Person B has Event 2

This way : Person A has 2 events, Person B has one event, Event 1 has one person, Event 2 has 2 persons.

How can I listen on changes on relationship o I can change counts on each two models (add, delete)?

I know I have to listen on `delete` events on `Contact` and `Event` model, so I can change counts on the other side part of the relationship

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925292/eloquent-attach-detach-sync-fires-any-event

Comment: https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot