# Laravel Eloquent events (attach, detach & sync)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I read about [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events) but didn't see any `attach`, `detach` or `sync` events there.

How to implement these Eloquent events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent attach/detach/sync fires any event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925292/eloquent-attach-detach-sync-fires-any-event)

Comment: https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

From Laravel 5.8 Pivot Model Events are dispatched like normal model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases#laravel-5.8

You just need to add `using(PivotModel::class)` to your relation and events will work on the PivotModel.

```
    class User extends Model 
    {
        public function roles()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(App\Role::class)->using(UserRolePivot::class);
        }
    }
```

And Pivot Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

class UserRolePivot extends Pivot
{
      protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => RoleAttached::class,
    'deleted' => RoleDeleted::class,
];
}
```

`Attach($id)` will dispatch Created and Creating

`Detach($id)` will dispatch Deleting and Deleted,

`Sync($ids)` will dispatch the needed events too [Created,Creating,Deleting,Deleted]

Only `dispatch()` with out id doesn't dispatch any event until now.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor refuses to add this to laravel core, even many people need these events, see laravel PR about that https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/14988

But here is a package which soles the problem : 
https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot

A package is well tested and well documented so many people started to use it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18173840)

Comment: ok, I updated my answer. My answer is a solution to the problem, many people have the same problem and I just want to help them...

Answer (score -2):

When attaching/detaching/syncing you are creating objects of related models. For example:

```
class User extends Model 
{
...
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Role::class)
    }
...
}
```

Calling:

```
$user->roles()->attach(1);
```

creates a record in a pivot table.

Make UserRole model with user_id and role_id and use its eloquent events.

```
class UserRole extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'role_id'];
}
```

Comment: I need event firing before and after (attach, detach and sync). Lets say I want to log those value.