# Updating laravel relationship data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

When we inserting or updating the data via Eloquent relationship model, which is the best approach to use?

Example

```
$user->profile->update(['salary' => 5000]);

vs
 
$user->profile()->update(['salary' => 5000]);
```

I understand that

1. $user->profile() will return the relationship class such as [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.html)
2. $user->profile will return the actual UserProfile model class

I somehow remember I saw someone recommended to use `$user->profile->update()` instead of `$user->profile()->update()` but I couldn't find the article or reference link anymore

However, I found that if `$user->profile` is null, then it might caused an error such as

`Call to a member function update() on null`

So will it be easier to use relationship function update all the time?

```
$user->profile()->create()
$user->profile()->update()
$user->profile()->save()
$user->profile()->delete()
```

Is there any situation we should use the `$user->profile->save()` instead?

Or should one use it when it is in the multiple nested relationship?

```
$user->profile->bank()->create()
$user->profile()->bank()->create()
```

### Update

reference link (for my own understanding)

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13568
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536
- [Eloquent attach/detach/sync fires any event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925292/eloquent-attach-detach-sync-fires-any-event)

### Conclusion

For now, will use code below in application, both will trigger events

```
if ($user->bank === null) {
    $user->bank()->save(new UserBankAccount($input)); // trigger created event
    // $user->bank()->create($input);// trigger created event
} else {
    $user->bank->update($input); // trigger updated event
    // $user->bank()->update($input); // will NOT trigger updated event
}
```

Comment: if you are on php8 you can use an null save method call `$user->profile?->update()`

Comment: thought that issue looked familiar ... glad i won't have to explain all that again `;)`

Comment: yeah, I am trying to write down the scenarios of each methods and pros and cons, so I could avoid making this mistakes in my code.

Comment: not sure if it is mentioned in the issues but one method will involve eloquent events and the other will not ... when calling `update` on a model instance will cause model events to be fired as `save` is called; the other method is a direct `update` call on the builder so no model events

Comment: Thanks, your comments is exactly the answer that what I looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use forceFill()

Example:

```
$user->bank->forceFill($data)->save();
```