# Can we use an observer on the attach method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-8, observer-pattern, observers

I would like to observe a pivot table in which, rows are created with an attach method in a specific model, is there a way to Observe that pivot table through the attach method that is responsible for creating rows?

Comment: I don't think you can observe the attach method itself but you can always make a [custom pivot model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) and attach observers on the appropriate events on that

Comment: I have answered myself with the solution, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after struggling some time, I came to answer my question,

so in order to observe a table whose rows are  created by the attach method, we will need to do 3 things

1- we will need to create a model that extends
`$Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`

2- Connect the model to the database  table with this line:

`protected $table = 'data_base_table_name';`

3- use the  method  'using' at the end of the BelongsToMany relationship in each model that is related to the pivot table

Example:

let's say we have a model called Student and another one called Group, we  have also a pivot table  called group_students that is filled with the attach method since we have a student  BelongsToMany groups and Group BelongsToMany  Students,

we will need to create a model named GroupStudent that  extends
`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`
and link it to the group_students by adding  the following line in  the GroupStudent Class:

`protected $table = 'group_student'`

After that, we will need to add the using method The BelongsToMany relations in  the Student Model and the Group Model like the following:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany(Student::class)->using(GroupStudent::class);
}
```

and

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class)->using(GroupStudent::class);
}
```

And here we go,  now whenever I create a row in the group_students table through the attach method, this will be observed and the method created will be executed.

Comment: In quite a few circumstances, you'll also need to use `->withPivot('id')` or whatever your primary key column is on the pivot table, and potentially other fields depending on your needs. Laravel/Eloquent doesn't not automatically select all pivot table fields, even if you're using a column pivot model that it return from `$relation->pivot`. That pivot object won't contain any of the attributes that aren't selected in `->withPivot()`. Apparently it's complicated, but it's a brutal concept to have to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking - looks like this explains Laravel 5.8+ supports this: [Eloquent attach/detach/sync fires any event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925292/eloquent-attach-detach-sync-fires-any-event)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).